# What does this mean by 'if the point p has same co-ordinates'?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity

[image]

I was learning Special Relativity from [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.csulb.edu/~wziemer/Papers/specialrelativity.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiF5IuEmfriAhXZMN4KHZRTBnsQFjALegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0WcM_M3r8ILMUGRK3Mxw-Y) pdf.

I'm talking about this part (second paragraph) in the screenshot (the whole screenshot is for more context):

"Seen from the point of view of the coordinate systems, if the point p
has the same coordinates, the point q will lie somewhere on a circle of radius pq
centered at p. Any Galilean transformation of coordinate systems will just put q
somewhere on this circle, see figure 8."

What does 'if point p has same co-ordinates' mean'? Isn't q always on the circle with centre p and radius pq, regardless of the co-ordinate system? Then why the additional condition 'if p has same co-ordinates'?

Also, why are the events p and q being treated differently in this discussion? I think that p is kept stationary in different co-ordinate systems, while q is moving. Is p the observer and q 'the event being observed'? If yes, then why isn't p at the origin of those co-ordinate systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does 'if point p has same co-ordinates' mean'? Isn't q always on the circle with centre p and radius pq, regardless of the co-ordinate system? Then why the additional condition 'if p has same co-ordinates'?

Yes. I have no idea why the additional condition was mentioned. Perhaps the author changed his mind what exactly he is about to say  halfway through and did not notice it.

> Also, why are the events p and q being treated differently in this discussion? I get the feeling that p is kept stationary in different co-ordinate systems, while q is moving. Is p the observer and q 'the event being observed'? If yes, then why isn't p at the origin of those co-ordinate systems?

No, p is not an observer. p is only an event - that is fixed point in spacetime. Observer has more characteristics like velocity or orientation which an event does not have. Also since p is fixed point of spacetime it does not have any velocity and cannot be stationary or nonstationary. It has no evolution in time.

In Euclidean case you simply take one slice of the whole spacetime that has constat time coordinate and one space coordinate and thus you are left with 2D space. The text revolves around definition of distances on this slice and how is the situation of 2 fixed points seen from the perspective of family of coordinates connected by galilean transformation. - that is under any (galilean) change of coordinates the point q will be found on the given circle.

In Minkowski case, the slice you take is that of a constancy of two spatial (spacelike) coordinates and you are left with 2D space that is timelike. In here it is obious that the events p and q has no time evolution, because one of the axes defines time coordinate and the points do not evolve with this coordinates. And as before, the text revolves around defining the distances on this slice and how is the relative position of two points seen from the perspective of family of coordinates connected by Lorentz transformation - that is under any (lorentzian) change of coordinates the coordinates of the point q will be found on the given hyperbola in $R^2$ space.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what these slices are? Is a slice just a 2D graph showing only two of the spacetime axes? If that's the case, then we shouldn't expect to have the distance pq preserved in each of these slices, right?

Comment: @Ryder Rude The slices are simply set of events with given condition. In the case of classical physics the condition is that the events happened at the same time. You are left with 3D euclidean space and the additional condition is that you také some 2D plane in this 3D space. With cartesian coordinates it could be for example set of events that have z-coordinate equal 0.In relativistic case the meaning is similar, but instead of events that happened at the same time you také events that have one more spatial coordinate constant.F.e. the slice could be set of events with y,z coordinates equal0